# Implementation multi sink in contiki

Tags: simulation, iot, contiki, sink

I want to implement program of multi sink sensor networks in `contiki`. I have two types of thing and each of networks of thing has a sink node that send data its sink. The sinks should communicate with themselves. According to the `Support of multiple sinks via a virtual root for the RPL routing protocol. EURASIP Journal on Wireless Communications and Networking 2014 2014:91` paper, sinks can communicate in several ways. For example Forward packet to correct sink, Forward packet to all sink and Forward packet to central unit. This paper focus on third method. But do not refer to implementation it in `contiki`. Is there an example for implement of communication between sinks in `contiki`?